Who inherited Isaac's Wealth?
The Bible says in Genesis 25:5 "Abraham gave everything he owned to his son Isaac" (NLT). That's straight forward. However, it is not clear who inherited Isaac's wealth.
The Bible states that Jacob obtained the claim for the birth right from Esau (Genesis 25:29–34) and also received his father's spiritual blessings (Genesis 27:27-29; 28:3-4). Nonetheless, in Jacob's own words, he only had his staff when he fled his home (Genesis 32:10). God blesses him abundantly in Paddan-Aram and by the time he returns home he has great wealth (Genesis 30:43). It seems like Esau was also wealthy (Genesis 33:9).
So who ended up with Isaac's wealth? Thank you for the help.

We are not told so we do not know.  It was probably Esau but we cannot be sure.

I believe the very reason we are not told is because it is so obvious that Esau got it. Parchment and ink was precious in those days...

The Bible does not spell out the obvious to us, God judging that we are able to trace from cause to inescapable effect - which is something Moses in Genesis absolutely belabours to bring before the reader.
Since Jacob fled due to his sin, and since Esau was Isaac's favourite AND NOW his only son still living with him, there was none to compete over who 'gets it all'. Esau becomes the logical inheritor. This is very clear from the account even though it is not spelled out, again, cause and effect.
In your description of the question you mention  something that must be pointed out about Isaac's material wealth and how it relates to the birth right. Wealth was only the consequence of the birth right, and not the birth right in and of itself. That this is the case can clearly be seen in the life of Jacob who, though he began with only a staff in his hand, accumulated wealth under God's blessing.
Contrary to the skewed popular beliefs of some, the birth-right is spiritual first and with it comes the promise of material blessings to its obedient possessor. That Jacob had long since repented of his sin of deceiving his dad becomes apparent when we consider him at the Jabbok. He wrestles with the Angel, and is not destroyed for refusing to let go of Him but instead blessed with a change of name (name being linked to character) as a recognition of the fact.

Short Answer: In the end we don't know. Let's look to scripture though.
Isaac’s wealth:

Genesis 26:13-14 - The man began to prosper, and continued prospering
until he became very prosperous; 14 for he had possessions of flocks
and possessions of herds and a great number of servants. So the
Philistines envied him.

Isaac himself became very wealthy. He had many flocks, herds, and servants.
Jacob and Esau:
Jacob obtained the birthright from Esau in Genesis 25:31-33:

31 But Jacob said, “Sell me your birthright as of this day.”
32 And Esau said, “Look, I am about to die; so what is this birthright
to me?”
33 Then Jacob said, “Swear to me as of this day.”
So he swore to him, and sold his birthright to Jacob.

Jacob also received his father’s spiritual blessings (Genesis 27:27-29; 28:3-4).

And he came near and kissed him; and he smelled the smell of his
clothing, and blessed him...

However, scripture says that Jacob fled from his home. It mentions that perhaps he only had his staff (Genesis 32:10).

10 I am not worthy of the least of all the mercies and of all the
truth which You have shown Your servant; for I crossed over this
Jordan with my staff, and now I have become two companies.

By the time he returned, he had acquired great wealth in Paddan-Aram (Genesis 30:43).

43 Thus the man became exceedingly prosperous, and had large flocks,
female and male servants, and camels and donkeys.

Esau’s wealth: Esau also appears to have been wealthy. We read in Genesis 33:9, Esau tells Jacob: “But Esau said, “I have enough, my brother; keep what you have for yourself.”
Conclusion:
In the end we don't know. The Bible does not explicitly state who inherited Isaac’s wealth. However, it is likely that both Jacob and Esau received portions of it. Jacob’s acquisition of the birthright and blessings would have given him a significant share, but Esau’s wealth might indicate that he also received a substantial inheritance.
If this be the case, then it seems that both Jacob and Esau ended up with portions of Isaac’s wealth. Jacob’s wealth grew significantly during his time in Paddan-Aram, while Esau also maintained considerable wealth.

Esau clearly had all of Isaac's assets up until Israel met him upon his return from Laban.  It seems unlikely that would have changed at Isaac's death without some mention being made in the record of scripture (Gen 32-35)

"clearly" — It's not at all clear when the appropriate scripture isn't quoted in the answer. If one is expected to read through over a hundred verses in order to find the relevant details, it isn't "clear".

“This very distinguished philosophy professor came out on the platform in front of this gang of students and took a bit of chalk and scrawled up a proposition in symbolic logic on the board. He turned to the audience and said, ‘Well now, ladies and gentlemen, I think you’ll agree that that’s obvious?’
“Then he looked at it a bit more and started to scratch his head and after a while he said, ‘Excuse me!’ And he disappeared.
“About half an hour later he came back beaming all over his face and said triumphantly, ‘Yes, I was right—it is obvious!’” — John Brunner, in Stand on Zanzibar.

The questioner accurately said that Jacob had received nothing from Isaac(0%) before he went to Laban.  So, until Jacob returns, that leaves 100% with Esau.  How is that not clear?

The OP failed to quote scripture, and this answer assumes that readers have done the missing research . If something is "clearly", it still needs a brief explanation as to why it is clear. Just because the question stated something, that doesn't make it a reliable source. ¶ The best answers are complete and self-contained. If someone asked me "Who inherited Isaac's Wealth?", and I replied by quoting your answer, it wouldn't be understandable or well received. If one must explain an answer it doesn't get a +1.

Note that the purpose of comments on this site is to improve the questions and answers, and that was my intent.  In this case, "Esau clearly had all of Isaac's assets up until Israel met him upon his return from Laban." is the significant key to answering the question. But to be a good answer the answer needs to supply supporting evidence of that statement.
